# List users unique although they appear multiple times in different countries

Tags: sql, postgresql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=088fcabde1d15ce1740a84a217c6bfa6)**

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    order_date DATE,
    country VARCHAR(255),
    customer VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO customers
(order_date, country, customer)
VALUES 
('2020-04-10', 'DE', 'user_01'),
('2020-04-15', 'AT', 'user_01'),
('2020-04-18', 'DE', 'user_02'),
('2020-04-22', 'DE', 'user_03'),
('2020-05-18', 'DE', 'user_04'),
('2020-05-26', 'AT', 'user_04'),
('2020-05-28', 'DE', 'user_05'),
('2020-06-03', 'AT', 'user_05'),
('2020-06-10', 'AT', 'user_06'),
('2020-06-15', 'AT', 'user_06'),
('2020-06-23', 'AT', 'user_07');
```

**Exptected Result:**

| order_date | country | customers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-04-10 | DE | user_01 |
| 2020-04-18 | DE | user_02 |
| 2020-04-22 | DE | user_03 |
| 2020-05-18 | DE | user_04 |
| 2020-05-28 | DE | user_05 |
| 2020-06-10 | AT | user_06 |
| 2020-06-23 | AT | user_07 |

---

In the expected result I want to **list the unique user** based on the following conditions:

1. If a user appears mutliple times it should only be displayed on the **first date it appears in DE**. If there is only an order_date in AT it should appear on the first date it appears in AT.
2. If a user appears both in DE and AT it **should only be displayed for DE in column country**. 
    `(e.g. user_01, user_04, user_05)`

---

So far I came up with this query:

```
SELECT
c.order_date,
c.country,
c.customer
FROM customers c
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY 1,2,3;
```

However, I have no clue how I have to change this query to get the expected result?

Comment: What if the first date  is AT  country ?

Comment: Good point. I changed the conditions in 1) accordingly. Always the date it appears the first time in DE should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use row_number. Country takes a priority over Date.

```
select order_date, country, customer
from (
  select
    c.order_date,
    c.country,
    c.customer,
      row_number() over(partition by c.customer order by case when c.country ='DE' then 1 else 2 end, c.order_date) rn 
  from customers c
  ) t
where rn = 1;
```

[db<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7c4eb4b71c80bcfb9c03ab1ff39b29f3)

Note I changed a line for user_06 to `('2020-06-15', 'DE', 'user_06')` to demonstrate a priority.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN country = 'DE' THEN order_date END), MIN(order_date)) order_date, 
       COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN country = 'DE' THEN country END), 'AT') country, 
       customer
FROM customers
GROUP BY customer
ORDER BY customer
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ed03e99980980b4bb46c9aecccbafa0b).

Answer (score 0):

Working just for your specific sample data, you can group by just the `Customer` column and appropriately aggregate the others:

```
SELECT
min(order_date) Order_Date,
max(country) Country,
customer
FROM customers
GROUP BY customer
ORDER BY customer;
```

See [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=72a0691435c9cb9cc50d799acfcc9e40)